# Cordova record output audio, not microphone

Tags: android, cordova, audio, record, capture

I'm making a sound grid app where users can make music. It would be great that users can record mixes, but I find no plugin to cordova that allows internal audio recording only encounter to record the microphone and that does not help me.

I am using crosswalk-project, a cordova external plugin can also be useful, but not find anything.

Thank you and sorry for my english.